# When two separate phrases both take the verb "lassen", is it common to use it only once at the end?

Tags: style

> {Sarcastically}: Ich ersuche Euch, Euren Hochmut außer Acht und ihr die Aufgabe zu **lassen**.

Given the fixed phrase "*etw. außer Acht lassen*", I would be tempted to place the verb "*(zu) lassen*" immediately after the word "*Acht*" and perhaps put some different verb after "*Aufgabe*".

But when the second part after "*und*" also takes the verb "*lassen*", is it common for native speakers to  think ahead and use it only once at the end?

Answer (score 4):

Note that you are using "lassen" in two different ways here, once inside an idiomatic expression ("außer Acht lassen" - "to ignore") and once in its usual meaning ("ihr die Aufgabe lassen" - "to leave the job to her"). Using "lassen" only once in this context constitutes what is known as **Zeugma** or **Syllepsis** ([wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis), lood at Type 3), and while Wikipedia apparently decided that that sort of thing is generally grammatically correct, it does sound *very* unnatural.

Saying it twice also sounds odd, since using the same word in the same position twice also sounds odd. The most natural way would probably be to find a formulation that expresses one of the two parts of the sentence differently.

In cases where you use the word the same way in both cases, it will be more natural to only put it once, e.g.:

> {Pointing a gun}: Ich ersuche Euch, mir Eure Geldbörse, und ihr Euren Gehrock zu lassen.

But you can also just put it in the first time:

> {Pointing a gun}: Ich ersuche Euch, mir Eure Geldbörse zu lassen, und ihr Euren Gehrock.

Answer (score 4):

There used to be a famous German comedian - Heinz Erhardt - who was well-known for forming such funny sentences (look up his stage performances on YouTube, he was very creative with the language). As has already been pointed out, the  form is that of a *Zeugma*, using a contracted verb in two slightly different meanings:

> Ich heiße nicht nur Heinz Erhardt sondern auch Sie herzlich willkommen!
>
> Ich fror vor mich hin, denn nicht nur meine Mutter, auch der Ofen war ausgegangen.

In your example, *lassen* is contracted from two slightly different forms:

1. Etwas außer Acht lassen (to disregard something)
2. Jemandem etwas lassen (to leave something to someone)

as you have realized already - which is exactly the joking form that Erhardt used. As you can see from the examples, sentences like that *can* be formed and are quite well understood, but from the fact that this stylistic form is used by a comedian you can deduce it sounds really funny to a native speaker. So, outside comedy, this is not common at all.

Things are a bit different when the contracted verb has *absolutely identical* notion for both cases - In this case, nothing is wrong or funny about contracting the two verbs into one. On the contrary, *not contracting* the verbs would sound unusual.

> Er ließ sowohl Kosten als auch Gefahren vollkommen außer Acht.
>
> Nicht nur meine Mutter, sondern auch mein Vater war ausgegangen.

Answer (score 3):

Both possible. Omitting "lassen" after Acht is higher style than using two different verbs in the sentence. It sounds kind of poetically.

Comment: ...poetically or at least rather "constructed". Not common in all day use, ISTM.

Answer (score 1):

In accordance with prior answers I can provide a source which condemns the omitting of one of the two *»lassen«*.

> Nicht möglich ist die Ersparung übereinstimmender Verbformen, die
> unterschiedlichen Konstruktionen oder festen Wendungen mit besonderer
> Bedeutung angehören; also nicht:
>
> Ich **habe** genügend Geld und die Rechnung zu bezahlen (Vollverb /
> Modalverb). Sie **ist** Ärztin und schon oft hier gewesen (Vollverb /
> Hilfsverb). Sie **warf** noch einen Blick auf ihn und er das Fenster zu
> (*einen Blick auf jemanden werfen / etwas zuwerfen*). (Ähnlich:) Die Uhr
> **schlug** Mitternacht und ich mit der Faust auf den Tisch. Sie **nahm**
> Seife, Schwamm und ein Bad.
>
> Bewusst eingesetzt, stellen diese Ersparungen ein Stilmittel (so
> genanntes [Zeugma](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zeugma)) zur Erzielung bestimmter (komischer) Wirkungen dar
> (*Nimm dir Zeit und nicht das Leben!*).
>
> <sub>Aus: Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch (Stichwort »Ellipse«; 1998)</sub>

So we have two options:

(1) Using *»lassen«* twice

(2) Rephrasing the sentence

> (1) Ich ersuche Euch, Euren Hochmut außer Acht zu lassen und ihr die
> Aufgabe zu lassen.

This case of repetition sounds horrible. A harmonious example would be:

> Wer Sorgen hat, hat auch Likör!
> ([Wilhelm Busch](http://www.wilhelm-busch-seiten.de/werke/helene/kapitel16.html))

Therefore the sentence should be rephrased, e. g. to

> (2a) Ich ersuche Euch, Euren Hochmut hintanzustellen und ihr die
> Aufgabe zu lassen.
>
> (2b) Ich ersuche Euch, Euren Hochmut außer Acht zu lassen und ihr die
> Aufgabe nicht wegzunehmen.